# Sharepoint Xpath Contains Issue

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, xpath

I wonder if anyone out there could help.

I'm new to Xpath & SharePoint 2010 but so far I have been getting along, but this little problem is causing me a big head ache!

What i'm trying to do is show the value in a field if there is not another value with a similar name in the same column in a SharePoint list (hopefully that makes sense).

I have the following select which works if you hard code the value to compare against 
`<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref[contains(.,'Test')]"/>` This will displays all values that have test in this case.

What i'm after is to compare the current selected Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref column against all other results in the Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref columns

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing!

*Update @Ian Here is the entire contents of the page in share point designer.

What I want it to do is remove the duplicate naming values and show the top value only i.e.

Current list

Test 1

Test 1

Hello 1

Robert 1

What I want

Test 1

Hello 1

Robert 1

Just to give a bit more information on the purpose of the SharePoint list. It is a form library that stores inputted forms, all the forms are submitted so every version is kept, The purpose of the view below is to show the latest version of the form only, then I will have another view which will show the other versions.

Please find the complete code from sharepoint designer below:

```
<code> 
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ListProperty Property="TitleOrFolder" runat="server"/> - 
<SharePoint:ListProperty Property="CurrentViewTitle" runat="server"/></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ListProperty Property="TitleBreadcrumb" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
            <span class="ms-ltviewselectormenuheader" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:ListTitleViewSelectorMenu AlignToParent="true" id="LTViewSelectorMenu" runat="server" />
            </span>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>
</asp:content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ViewIcon Width="145" Height="54" runat="server"/></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
<SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu runat="server" id="RecentChanges"/>
<SharePoint:ModifySettingsLink runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId ="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server">
    <div height="100%" class="ms-pagemargin"><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width='6' height='1' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
        <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server" Description="" PartOrder="2" Default="TRUE" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID="" Title="Demand Management" ViewFlag="5" AllowConnect="True" DisplayName="Main View" PageType="PAGE_DEFAULTVIEW" FrameState="Normal" PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="NonSensitiveData" Dir="Default" DetailLink="/Strategy-and-Architecture/Business-Account-Managers/Demand Management" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="cafbbdc7-079d-4ae1-bf40-4a695834e510" ListName="{CAFBBDC7-079D-4AE1-BF40-4A695834E510}" FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ViewGuid="{1766D7BE-7DC0-4277-8418-EBA815716C60}" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ViewContentTypeId="0x" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." HelpMode="Modeless" ID="g_1766d7be_7dc0_4277_8418_eba815716c60" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" TitleUrl="/Strategy-and-Architecture/Business-Account-Managers/Demand Management" ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{1766D7BE-7DC0-4277-8418-EBA815716C60}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" __designer:CustomXsl="fldtypes_Ratings.xsl" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><ParameterBindings>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
            <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)" />
            <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
<XmlDefinition>
            <View Name="{1766D7BE-7DC0-4277-8418-EBA815716C60}" DefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Main View" Url="/Strategy-and-Architecture/Business-Account-Managers/Demand Management/Forms/Main View.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/dlicon.png">
                <Query/>
                <ViewFields>
                    <FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Txtdescription"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Status_x0020_Hidden"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Ddl_x0020_DM_x0020_Project_x0020_Status"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Modified"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Editor"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Txt_x0020_Version"/>
                    <FieldRef Name="Title" Explicit="TRUE"/>
                </ViewFields>
                <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
                <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
            </View>
        </XmlDefinition>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<Xsl>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"> 
  <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/> 
  <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/internal.xsl"/> 
            <xsl:param name="AllRows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[$EntityName = '' or (position() &gt;= $FirstRow and position() &lt;= $LastRow)]"/>
            <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">'</xsl:param>
            <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='LinkFilename']" name="LinkFilenameNoMenu.LinkFilename" mode="Computed_LinkFilename_body" ddwrt:tag="a" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
                <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
                <xsl:param name="ShowAccessibleIcon" select="0"/>
                <xsl:param name="folderUrlAdditionalQueryString"/>
                <xsl:param name="IncludeOnClick" select="1"/>
                <xsl:choose>

                    <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@FSObjType='1'">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$RecursiveView">
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef" />
          </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:variable name="FolderURL">
              <xsl:value-of select="$PagePathFinal" />RootFolder=<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileRef.urlencode" /><xsl:value-of select="$ShowWebPart"/>&amp;FolderCTID=<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ContentTypeId" />&amp;View=<xsl:value-of select="$View"/><xsl:value-of select="$folderUrlAdditionalQueryString"/>
            </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="$IsDocLib">
                                        <xsl:variable name="OnMouseDownJS">
                  javascript:VerifyFolderHref(this,event,'<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@File_x0020_Type.url" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@File_x0020_Type.progid" />','<xsl:value-of select="$XmlDefinition/List/@DefaultItemOpen" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@serverurl.progid" />');return false;
                </xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:variable name="OnClickJS">
                  return HandleFolder(this,event,&quot;<xsl:value-of select="$PagePathFinal" />RootFolder=&quot; + escapeProperly(&quot;<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileRef" />&quot;) + '<xsl:value-of select="$ShowWebPart" />&amp;FolderCTID=<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ContentTypeId" />&amp;View=<xsl:value-of select="$View" /><xsl:value-of select="$folderUrlAdditionalQueryString"/>','TRUE','FALSE','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@File_x0020_Type.url" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@File_x0020_Type.progid" />','<xsl:value-of select="$XmlDefinition/List/@DefaultItemOpen" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@serverurl.progid" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@CheckoutUser.id" />','<xsl:value-of select="$Userid" />','<xsl:value-of select="$XmlDefinition/List/@ForceCheckout" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@IsCheckedoutToLocal" />','<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@PermMask" />');
                </xsl:variable>
                <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="{$FolderURL}">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="$IncludeOnClick = '1'">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="onmousedown">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$OnMouseDownJS"/>
                      </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$OnClickJS"/>
                      </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef" />
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="$ShowAccessibleIcon">
                      <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" border="0" width="1" height="1" alt="{$idPresEnabled}" />
                    </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                </a>
              </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:variable name="OnClickJS">
                  javascript:EnterFolder(&quot;<xsl:value-of select="$PagePathFinal" />RootFolder=&quot; + escapeProperly(&quot;<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileRef" />&quot;) + '<xsl:value-of select="$ShowWebPart" />&amp;FolderCTID=<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ContentTypeId" />&amp;View=<xsl:value-of select="$View" /><xsl:value-of select="$folderUrlAdditionalQueryString" />');return false;
                </xsl:variable>
                <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="{$FolderURL}">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="$IncludeOnClick = '1'">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$OnClickJS"/>
                      </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef" />
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="$ShowAccessibleIcon">
                      <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" border="0" width="1" height="1" alt="{$idPresEnabled}" />
                    </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                </a>
              </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
        <a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="{$thisNode/@FileRef}" onmousedown="return VerifyHref(this,event,'{$XmlDefinition/List/@DefaultItemOpen}','{$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon}','{$thisNode/@serverurl.progid}')" 
           onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','{$thisNode/@File_x0020_Type.url}','{$thisNode/@File_x0020_Type.progid}','{$XmlDefinition/List/@DefaultItemOpen}','{$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type.File_x0020_Type.mapcon}','{$thisNode/@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type}','{$thisNode/@serverurl.progid}','{$thisNode/@CheckoutUser.id}','{$Userid}','{$XmlDefinition/List/@ForceCheckout}','{$thisNode/@IsCheckedoutToLocal}','{$thisNode/@PermMask}')">
          <xsl:value-of select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[1]" />

          <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@FileLeafRef.Name" /></a>

                        <xsl:if test="$thisNode/@Created_x0020_Date.ifnew='1'">
                            <xsl:call-template name="NewGif">
                                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="FieldRef_Text_body.Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" match ="FieldRef[@Name='Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref']" mode="Text_body" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>


<!---  This is the field I wish to change --->

 <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref[contains(.,'Test')]"/> 

  </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet></Xsl>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>

</ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ListProperty CssClass="ms-listdescription" Property="Description" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:SPCalendarNavigator id="CalendarNavigatorId" runat="server"/>
  <ApplicationPages:CalendarAggregationPanel id="AggregationPanel" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>

</code>
```

Comment: Can you given an example of the XML you're working with and what sort of output you expect?

Comment: @Ian - Thanks for your response. Here is there row from the sharepoint list


<code><xsl:template name="FieldRef_Text_body.Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" match ="FieldRef[@Name='Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref']" mode="Text_body" ddwrt:ghost="" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
     <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>

<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Txt_x0020_Doc_x0020_Ref[contains(.,'Test')]"/> 
 
  </xsl:template></code>

Comment: What i want it to do is hide the duplicated values in the row.

At the moment I have a list which looks like this

test 1
test 1
Hello 1

New List

Test 1
Hello 1

Comment: code blocks don't work very well in comments, please _edit_ the original question, and add an example of the input XML as well as the XSLT you have so far. To preserve formatting, indent the code with four leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

On the tables select statement change the "AllRows" select statement to the following

This will then display only one result of the same document name, then add a order by clause in the xml as show below to display the latest result.

```
    <Query>
                <OrderBy>
                    <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"/>
                </OrderBy>
                <GroupBy>
                </GroupBy>
            </Query>
```